# Adding extra elements to options array in Zend_Form_Element_Select

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Basically, I need an extra bit of data to be included in a select box which is created with Zend. The current markup is as follows:

```
<select>
    <option label="Canadian Dollar ($)" value="1">Canadian Dollar ($)</option>
    <option label="Euro (€)" value="2">Euro (€)</option>
    <option label="US Dollar ($)" value="3">US Dollar ($)</option>
</select>
```

The markup I'm trying to achieve is as follows (notice the additional 'data-curreny-type' attribute):

```
<select>
    <option label="Canadian Dollar ($)" value="1" data-currency-code="CAD">Canadian Dollar ($)</option>
    <option label="Euro (€)" value="2" data-currency-code="EUR">Euro (€)</option>
    <option label="US Dollar ($)" value="3" data-currency-code="USD">US Dollar ($)</option>
</select>
```

The form is being created using Zend as follows:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Select(self::NAME);

/* -- OMMITED DB CODE --*/

$element->setOptions($options);
```

$options is an array in the form of: array('1' => 'Value1', '2'=> 'Value2').. etc.

My qestion is, is there any way of adding extra elements into the 'options' element using Zend ->setOptions($opts)? Or anything I might not be aware of.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

The `FormSelect` view helper which renders the element does not support additional attributes on the `<option>` tags, so the only way to achieve this would be to override that helper with your own implementation. The helper class is `Zend_View_Helper_FormSelect`, so if you take a look at the code for that you should be able to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please use setArribute method to add an additional attribute. You can add data-currency-code as an attribute.

Comment: Wont' work.. because the attribs get added to the 'select' tag. I need it added to the 'options' tag. But thanks anyway. Any more suggestions?